# Running commands remotely returns unexpected output

Tags: bash, awk, ssh, kill, kill-process

I want to kill a process remotely and I use `ssh -i` command like this:

```
ssh -i $app_rsa_file_path $app_server_user@$app_server_ip "ps aux | grep java | grep billing | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

if I run command directly on the server, it works fine; but in remote version it seems that `awk` has no effect and the command passes the whole output of `ps aux | grep java | grep billing` to `kill` and I get this:

```
kill: invalid option -- 'D'

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
 <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
 -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
 -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see kill(1).
```

Any idea about the reason?

Comment: i think u need to escape the $ in ssh cmd.

Comment: Yes @LeeHoYo, that was the trick. Thanks. Could you please add it as an answer?

Comment: As ever, `grep foo | grep bar | awk '{ baz }'` is [better](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) written `awk '/foo/ && /bar/ { baz }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use double-quotes " so you need to escape the $ special character: